# Blank space is being created to the right of my webpage?

Tags: html, css

I have found previous questions related to this, but I can't seem to find any solution that would help my problem. When the browser width is 718px or less, blank space to the right of the webpage is being created, and it becomes increasingly larger as the browser size gets smaller... how do I fix this?

This code can be found on this website: http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina/cucinamobile.html

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#logo {
  top: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 250px;
}
#newwhiteline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  top: -40px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#whiteline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: white;
}
a.logo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
}
.firstlist {
  position: relative;
  left: -17px;
  margin-top: -23px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li.list1 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 9px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#underline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
a.list {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
a.list:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
a.cucinaclass {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
a.cucinaclass:hover {
  background-color: none;
}
span.cucina {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: matteosfont;
  src: url(../fonts/riesling.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: cooperfont;
  src: url(../fonts/fbsbltc.ttf);
}
#whitebox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.headercucina {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 31px;
  left: 25px;
  top: -5px;
}
#underline2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  top: 26px;
}
#images {
  position: relative;
}
#brekkie {
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.lunchbox {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.dinnerbox {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.drinksbox {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.secondlist2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
span.coopert {
  color: white;
  font-family: cooperfont;
  font-size: 16px;
}
span.coopertt {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#fb2 {
  width: 35px;
}
#insta2 {
  width: 35px;
}
#agfg2 {
  width: 35px;
}
li.listtt {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.homebaby:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.instababy:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.agfgbaby:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
span.coopert:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.lunchbox:hover {
  border: 5px solid #F4EF7F;
}
.dinnerbox:hover {
  border: 5px solid #F4EF7F;
  /*#F4EF7F Credit Riley Pettigrew*/
}
.drinksbox:hover {
  border: 5px solid #F4EF7F;
}
#brekkie:hover {
  border: 5px solid #F4EF7F;
}
#homer {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  color: black;
}
.firstlistt {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: cooperfont;
  src: url(fonts/fbsbltc.ttf);
}
span.coopert {
  color: white;
  font-family: cooperfont;
}
span.coopertt {
  color: white;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 370px) {
  #logo {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  span.main {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  #header {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
a.cooper {
  font-family: cooperfont;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>di Matteos - Cucina</title>
  <link href="cucinamobilestylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="../images/fatty.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width = device-width, user-scalable = no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="whiteline"></div>
    <a class="logo" href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au">
      <img id="logo" src="../images/diMatteos2.png" />
    </a>
    <div id="newwhiteline"></div>
    <ul class="firstlist">
      <a class="list" href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au">
        <li class="list1"><strong>HOME</li></a>
<a class = "list" href = "http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina"><li class = "list1" id = "homer">CUCINA</span></li></a>
<a class = "list" href = "http://www.dimatteos.com.au/espresso"><li class = "list1">ESPRESSO</strong>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a class="list" href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/functions">
        <li class="list1"><strong>FUNCTIONS</li></a>
<a class = "list" href = "http://www.dimatteos.com.au/gallery"><li class = "list1">GALLERY</li></a>
<a class = "list" href = "http://www.dimatteos.com.au/contact"><li class = "list1">CONTACT</strong>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    <div id="underline"></div>
    <div id="whitebox">
      <div class="headercucina"><strong><a class = "cucinaclass" href = "http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina">CUCINA</a></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="underline2"></div>
    <div id="images">
      <img class="blackempty" src="../images/black.png" />
      <a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina/breakfast">
        <img class="breakfastbox" id="brekkie" src="../images/breakfastboxbb.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina/lunch">
        <img class="lunchbox" src="../images/lunchboxbb.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina/dinner">
        <img class="dinnerbox" src="../images/dinnerbox.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina/drinks">
        <img class="drinksbox" src="../images/drinksbox.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <center>
      <ul class="firstlistt">
        <a class="homebaby" href="http://www.facebook.com/matteosforries" target="_blank">
          <li class="listtt">
            <img id="fb2" src="../images/facebookcircle.png" />
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="instababy" href="http://www.instagram.com/dimatteosforries" target="_blank">
          <li class="listtt">
            <img id="insta2" src="../images/instagramcircle.png" />
          </li>
        </a>
        <a class="agfgbaby" href="http://www.agfg.com.au/guide/45328/nsw/central-coast-nsw/central-coast-nsw/forresters-beach/restaurants-dining/di-matteos" target="_blank">
          <li class="listtt">
            <img id="agfg2" src="../images/agfgcircle.png" />
            </strong>
          </li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </center>
    <center>
      <ul class="secondlist2">
        <li class="bar2"><span class="coopertt">Website by </span><a class="cooper" href="http://www.coopertimewell.com" target="_blank"><span class = "coopert">CooperTimewell.com</span></li></a>
      </ul>
    </center>
    <!--
DON'T TOUCH THIS DIV !-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any blank space being created apart from what you have set in your CSS. I've tested it on chrome and firefox. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you resizing your browser? Have a look at http://www.dimatteos.com.au/cucina on a mobile and you will see what I mean

Comment: Yes, I have been resizing the browser. The problem exists on mobile, but appears fine on desktop browsers. Have you tried setting `overflow: hidden;` for your `#container` class?

Comment: Yes and that works fine for all mobile devices except Apple devices... when the overflow-x is hidden, you are still able to scroll horizontally on an apple device... do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Testing for mobile is such a pain. I can only suggest simple edits and have you test them yourself since I can't get the Stack Snippets from being run on my phone if I modify it as my own solution. Anyway, what happens when you do add `position: relative;` to your `#container` class?

Comment: Nothing changes, still blank space.

Comment: Also you should specify that this only happens on Apple devices if that is the case. This would save others time from scratching their head like I had to do when initially testing your snippet.

Comment: It doesn't just occur on Apple devices... it occurs on all mobile devices but I can do a dodgy fix for non-Apple devices.

Comment: Then at least fix your post to state that this is a mobile-only issue.

Comment: It's not... It makes the same blank space on my laptop too (when I resize the browser).

Comment: I tested the code you posted on an iPhone and there's no blank space on the right. Probably a live link to the problem page in question would be necessary, or a code sample that includes the problem.

Comment: i don't get it, can anyone explain me more where is the blank space he talking about? screenshot please

Comment: @ralph.m I have added a link to the live website, would you be able to test the code using this link and see if you get any blank space?

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz http://uploadpie.com/dbNVW

Comment: what mobile phone you are using? i don't see any blank space.

Comment: iPhone @FiidoFirdauz

Comment: @CoopDaddio — OK, post an answer based on your live link.

Comment: @CoopDaddio why so much repetitive code? all the rules for `#brekkie, .lunchbox, .dinnerbox, .drinks` are the same. Also I can't see the problem, have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have finally found the answer.

Thankyou to ralph.m who found half the problem - it involved the "blackempty" img class that simply had to be removed.

However, there is still a slight amount of black space with this gone, caused by the class ".headercucina"... in the CSS document, it is told to move left 25px... this is creating the black space. To fix this, you must simply change left: 25px to margin-left: 25px

:)

Answer (score 0):

add this into your css.

CSS

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

this will remove the blank space.

Comment: While this might work, I think it's better to address the elements that cause the problem directly.

Comment: of course this will work, but better way is to address the specific element which occur the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after looking at your live site, it's this image (inside your `#images` div) that is causing the space to the right:

```
<img class="blackempty" src="../images/black.png">
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of that image is, but it's causing the issue, and I'm sure there's a better solution than using an image anyhow.

Comment: Although this worked a lot, there is still a slight amount of black space being made

Comment: I think it has something to do with the logo but I'm not sure